# Find and log missing/wrong named columns in Excel using SSIS 2012

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis

I am new to SSIS. I am using SSIS 2012 to transfer data from Excel(COZYROC Excel Source Plus component) to SQL server database(OLE DB Destination). My requirement is whenever columns in the excel are not matched with mapped columns or any columns are missing, I should log the error message in the database.
Please help to resolve this problem.

Comment: Add a task to the OnError handler to do some kind of logging.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that is possible.

SSIS (and SSRS and other applications) require a 'contract' between source and destination such that any changes to the source will throw a mapping error and force the developer to re-map the data flow.

SSIS is not capable of a scenario such as 'if the source columns change, pump the rest and log the changes to another path'.

This is also an example of why Excel makes a terrible data source for a normalized database/ETL project, because users can easily change the Excel doc in such a way that would break data mapping.

Good luck.